# Category theory? Logic? Anyone experienced this like me?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, foundations

Mathematics is not logic, but if one uses Zorn's lemma and stuff he should accept logical impact on mathematics. I'm the one who cares *a lot* about logics.

It seems like Category theory is inevitable in every branch of mathematics at some level. However, category theory is kind of different logical framework than the standard set theory ZFC. I read articles about this paradoxical situation over and over, but still I am not satisfied. **It seems like people are switching their logical framework from one to another whenever they need**

I found that *the only* known way to do Category theory in ZFC is to accept "Grothendieck's universe" which is equivalent to the existence of strongly inaccessible cardinal.

I think this is really painful since inaccesible cardinal axiom proves *the consistency of ZFC*.

Is there anyone who had been suffered for accepting Category theory? What was your solution?

Comment: I know that this post is inappropriate to SE, but I really need help.. Please

Comment: Thats not true, you can have a much weaker form of large cardinals axiom, i.e., ZF having a transitive model in wich you could in principle talk about some related concepts of NBG or category in general (but not in its full power)

Comment: Having a transitive model is not as convenient. When category theorists adopt a universe axiom it is always for convenience...

Comment: And $\sf ZFC$ proves the consistency of Zermelo's set theory, which in turn proves the consistency of second-order arithmetic, which proves the consistency of Peano arithmetic. What's the big deal? $\sf ZFC$ is not holy that way.

Comment: @Asaf So do you mean that, if you were me, you would accept large cardinal axiom without worrying? Maybe I'm hesitating too much since I'm afraid to deform my logical context (namely ZFC) which I have been used ever since I started mathematics..

Comment: Yes, of course I'd accept it. I can understand where you're coming from. I had that feeling myself. But this is like accepting the fact that there are irrational numbers, and then accepting the fact that there are transcendental numbers. For a lot of things that you want to do, you can do them with just integers, or rational numbers. But irrational, and transcendental numbers, can simplify some things sometimes. Once you understand that foundational theories are not holy, and that you were really only using something much weaker, there's no issue adding more axioms. [...]

Comment: [...] In particular there's little issue with axioms as natural as the existence of inaccessible cardinals. Because it's a very reasonable assumption (whereas much larger large cardinals can be portrayed as less natural in some sense). So just assuming there is an inaccessible cardinal, or even that there are many inaccessible cardinals, is not an issue. It's fine.

Comment: @Asaf That's what exactly I wanted to know. 100% satisfied. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can do plenty of category theory without any assumptions about Grothendieck universes. Indeed, all the basic concepts do just fine: functors, natural transformations, etc.  There are certain things for which Grothendieck universes are helpful - but there are things in set theory for which inaccessible cardinals are equally useful.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Since you've had that feeling yourself, perhaps you could think up a more coherent title for this question? I tried and failed.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are reasons to have a pragmatic attitude to sets in category theory (and perhaps in all mathematics). I like the way that Adamek-Herrlich-Strecker present this topic in [*Abstract and Concrete Categories*](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) p. 13-16:

> Someone working, for example, in algebra, topology, or computer
>   science usually isn’t (and needn’t be) bothered with such
>   set-theoretical difficulties. But it is essential that those who work
>   in category theory be able to deal with “collections” like those
>   mentioned above. To do so requires some foundational restrictions.
>   Nevertheless, certain naturally arising categorical constructions
>   should not be outlawed simply because of the foundational safeguards.
>   Hence, what is needed is a foundation that, on the one hand, is
>   sufficiently flexible so as not to unduly inhibit categorical inquiry
>   and, on the other hand, is sufficiently rigid to give reasonable
>   assurance that the resulting theory is consistent, i.e., does not lead
>   to contradictions.

For most mathematicians the big deal with axiomatic set theory is that it proves that sets exists and that it give rules how sets can be created.

In ACC the hierarchy sets-classes-conglomerates is used to present category theory.